# on what does the error_reporting directive impacts?

Tags: php, error-reporting

from what I have read this directive specifies what type of errors will be reported to the script output (if display errors is on) or will be reported to the error_logs if log_errors is ON.

why in the following script I set the **`error_reporting`** to 0 ( turns off error_reporting ) and still got the message that describes the fatal error?

```
<?php
error_reporting(0) ; 

function a(&$name)
{

}

a("gg") ; // cause a fatal error, and display the message 

echo "gg" ;

?>
```

Error is:

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `error_reporting` is a function call, it has to be executed so it can take effect. But before anything in the script can be executed, the entire script has to be parsed. If there's a parse error, nothing runs, so it can't change the error reporting. So parse errors are always reported according to the error reporting setting in `php.ini`.

In the case of your script, when a function is declared to take a reference parameter, that changes how calls to the function are parsed. Instead of allowing any expression as the argument, it requires it to have the syntax of a variable. Since `"gg"` is not a variable, you get a fatal error during parsing.

`error_reporting` controls reporting of errors that can only be detected at runtime, usually due to the values of variables. As an example:

```
$numerator = 1;
$denominator = 0;

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
echo "WIth error reporting: ";
echo $numerator/$denominator;
echo "<br>";

error_reporting(0);

echo "WIthout error reporting: ";
echo $numerator/$denominator;
echo "<br>";
```

This will report an error for the first division, but not the second:

```
WIth error reporting: 
Warning: Division by zero in /private/var/folders/ts/tsRTg2iv2RW88k+8ZOgz7++++TY/-Tmp-/1B4537F5-61D1-487A-9062-9204D7A058D3 on line 9

WIthout error reporting:
```

Comment: but the message I got was "fatal error:" and not "parse error:".

Comment: This error is still detected during parsing, it just doesn't call itself a parse error.

Comment: can you give me in you're answer, a code sample that usually raises a fatal error but because of setting the error_reporting(0) then the message will not be displayed

Comment: ok you are right, I threw an exception and didn't caught it and it didn't show me the fatal error message

Comment: I added an example of division by zero.

Comment: "Parse error" means that the code does not comply with the PHP syntax. This is not the case: you have valid syntax, it's just you're attempting to do an operation that is not allowed.

Comment: I guess a better way to describe it is that the distinction is between errors that can be detected with static analysis, versus errors related to dynamic runtime data.